# Every piecewise linear function can be written as a sum

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g$ be a real valued piecewise linear function on some interval $[a,b]$ such that if we divide $[a,b]$ into $k$ pieces, $g$ is linear on each piece. Then, for some $d, a_1,...,a_k, c_1,...,c_k$, $g(x)=d+\sum_{i}^{k} a_i|x-c_i|$. How can I justify that?

Comment: I don't think the $k$ pieces are necessarily *equal*. And the $b$ in the expression for $g$ should be a different variable than the right end of the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Note that the function $$x\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^ka_i|x-c_i| $$ is continuous and (assuming $a=c_1<c_2<\ldots <c_k=b$) is linear in each interval $[c_i,c_{i+1}]$ with slope $\sum_{i\le k}a_i-\sum_{i>k}a_i$. Let $m_i$ be the slopes of the given function in $[c_i,c_{i+1}]$. Can you find suitable $a_i$ then? What is missing after that?